# Leaflet JS - changing esri shape into marker on certain zoom level

Tags: javascript, leaflet, shapefile, esri

I'm using [leaflet.shapefile](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet.shapefile) plugin with [Leaflet JS](http://leafletjs.com/index.html), and I'm trying to change the esri shape/polygon into normal marker icons depending on a certain zoom level

The plugin allows me to upload a zipfile onto our webserver, which then is processed by the plugin and added as a layer into Leaflet JS

```
var properties = new L.Shapefile('data/Test.zip', { style: propertyStyle, onEachFeature: propertyOnEachFeature })
```

What I would like to achieve: when the user zoomed in the polygon shape is visible, however when the user zooms above zoomlevel 10, it should display a marker instead, as the esri shape/polygons are very small and nearly not visible.

The zooming in and out part was easily done with:

```
map.on('zoomend', function() {
    if (map.getZoom() <10){
        if (map.hasLayer(properties)) {
            map.removeLayer(properties);
        } else {
            console.log("no property layer active");
        }
    }
    if (map.getZoom() >= 10){
        if (map.hasLayer(properties)){
            console.log("property layer already added");
        } else {
            map.addLayer(properties);
        }
    }
}
```

However I dont know how to change the L.ShapeFile to a L.Marker or what the right approach would be. 
Thanks for the help and advice.

**UPDATE**

The answer 'IvanSanchez' provided me was exactly what i was looking for.
With this a simple plugin '[Leaflet.Deflate](https://github.com/oliverroick/Leaflet.Deflate)' I was able to simply convert any shape, polygon, circle or line to a marker and all it took was to include the plugin js and a one liner:

```
L.Deflate({minSize: 20}).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [Leaflet.Deflate plugin](https://github.com/oliverroick/Leaflet.Deflate).

Comment: thanks IvanSanchez, this is exactly what I was looking for, works like a charm.

Comment: HI Ivan, would you be able to have a look at my follow up from the question above, my question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40489828/leaflet-js-leaflet-deflate-changing-default-marker-icon-to-custom-icon, thanks in advance